# Test if the directory has a specific name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Is there a way to test if a directory has a specific name and do some action? For instance, I have these ones:

```
/home/Al/dir
/home/Fl/dir
/usr/.../dir
```

If `pwd` returns any of these directories I want the test to return true (also for all directories ending with `dir` like this `/.../.../dir`). Is there a way to perform such a test?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, compare it as any other string. You don't even have to save `pwd` anywhere, as it is also available as `$PWD`. Use the left trim operator to remove everything before the last slash (inclusive):

```
   if [[ "${PWD##*/}" == "dir" ]]; then
     something --special
   fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Try this.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRNAME=dir
CHECKING_DIR=$1

if [ $(basename $CHECKING_DIR) = "$DIRNAME" ]; then 
    .. do some action ..
else
    .. do some action ..
fi


bash$ ./script /var/log/dir
```

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
 if [[ $(basename $(pwd)) == "dir" ]]; then
  ..
 else
  ..
 fi
```